# locksmithd doesn't work properly with etcd tls

Tags: ssl, coreos, etcd

I have CoreOS beta (1153.4.0) installed.

I have etcd2 configured with tls and works properly.

I'm trying to configure locksmithd to work with the tls certificates by updating `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data` and adding:

```
coreos:
   locksmith:
   endpoint: "https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379,https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379"
   etcd_cafile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
   etcd_certfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem
   etcd_keyfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem
```

which created the file `/run/systemd/system/locksmithd.service.d/20-cloudinit.conf` with the content:

```
[Service]
Environment="LOCKSMITHD_ENDPOINT=https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379"
Environment="LOCKSMITHD_ETCD_CAFILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
Environment="LOCKSMITHD_ETCD_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
Environment="LOCKSMITHD_ETCD_KEYFILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
```

`locksmithctl status` returns `Error initializing etcd client: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured`.

how can I debug this issue further? or even better.. solve it? :)

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: created a bug report at https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1595

Answer (score 0):

needed to run `systemctl unmask update-engine.service` on both servers and now locksmithd runs properly, if I lock one of the servers, the other one notices it with 'locksmithctl status'.

everything works.